# material UI table shows glitch and small spaces between columns with while resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a table with more than 13 columns. When I resize the table (to smaller screen size), it sometimes shows small spaces between columns, some of them having a glitch of some table data. Between columns I put no borders or else. Please help or give me some idea to fix this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include some code please. And what have you tried?

Comment: it is a piece of stinky codes. i already found i conditionally have a border on one left most cell, and somehow it push the other's border 1px to right. it doesnt affect the table until i tried it on chrome hic

Comment: Lol Good luck with that, then. I'm glad you were able to find the root of the problem.